# Check if textbox has value then disable form element

Tags: jquery

If my textbox has text in it, I want to disable the drop down list.  The textbox id is "newAccessPoint" and the drop down list id is "selectAccessPoint"

jQuery:

```
if ($.trim($('#newAccessPoint').val()).length() != 0) {
    $('#selectAccessPoint').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

HTML markup:

```
<table class="data-table">
    <tr>
        <td><label for ="AccessPoint" class="xl">Access Point:</label></td>
            <td><%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccessPointsList.Id, Model.AccessPointsList.AccessPoints.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.AsDecimal()), new { @id = "selectAccessPoint", @class = "info1"})%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for ="AccessPoint" class="xl">Or Add New:</label></td>
        <td><%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AccessPointsList.AccessPoint, new { @id = "newAccessPoint", @class = "location info2 xl", maxlength = "250" }) %></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: it's `.length` not `.length()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have `length()`. [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) is a property, not an object. You need to use just `length`.

```
if ($.trim($('#newAccessPoint').val()).length != 0) {
    $('#selectAccessPoint').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Depending on which version of jQuery you're using, you'll want to use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`:

```
if ($.trim($('#newAccessPoint').val()).length != 0) {
    $('#selectAccessPoint').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

**Edit (from comments)**:

Here is a **[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/ZSBKw/)** of this in use on textbox `input`, which disables the `select` element when the textbox has content, then re-enables it when it is cleared.

Comment: well `attr()` worked before when I had this set up just to look for a `keypress()` but I will change it to `prop()` I suppose.  However, typing in my textbox does not disable my drop down list even with using `length` as a property

Comment: `attr()` works because you're changing the attribute, however `prop()` was introduced to cater for boolean attributes. `disabled` is a boolean attribute. Where are you calling the `if` statement? You'll need to trigger it on user input, using `$('#myContainer').on('input', '#myTextbox', function() { ... });`

Comment: My idea could be wrong here but basically I just want to disable the dropdownlist if text is entered into the textbox, or disable the textbox if the dropdownlist has a changed value allowing only one or the other.  So the if statement would only be attached to the form controls.  Also, my version of JQuery doesn't support `prop()`

Comment: @Jared I've whipped up a JSFiddle to show this exact code in use: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/ZSBKw/

Comment: I see that and I appreciate that, but this isn't the only input on the webpage.  To use that would I have to put this input in its own `div` to differentiate any input here from the rest of the page?

Comment: [IDs are **unique**.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) You should only have one `#newAccessPoint` and one `#selectAccessPoint` on your page. This code will *only* check the length of the textbox with the unique ID of "newAccessPoint", and from that it will *only* disable the select element with the unique ID of "selectAccessPoint".

Comment: Yes, you can only have only one element with a ID on the whole page. That's what ID is meant to be..

Comment: Oh, right.  I missed the part where it says `'input', '#newAccessPoint'`. Duh.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, I hate to keep bothering you, but my version of JQuery doesn't support the method `.on` there.  Is there any other way you can think of?  We can move this to chat if need be if you have the time...

Comment: You should be able to use `live` in that case. I haven't used it in a while, but I believe it would be `$('#newAccessPoint').live('input', function() { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

Try this using the [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) method properly and [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
if ($.trim($('#newAccessPoint').val()).length != 0) {
    $('#selectAccessPoint').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't seem to be working and I can't imagine why.  Like I said to James down there, I could disable it using `keypress()` but not by checking the length so far...

Comment: @Jared: Could you post the HTML and the related js code in your question? That would help. May be post a functional example that illustrates your problem on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I have added the HTML code which defines the form controls I am trying to manipulate.  The JQuery code that I posted is the only js code that is related to this.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`onBlur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event handler:

```
<input type="text" id="newAccessPoint">
<select id="selectAccessPoint">
    <option>test</option>
</select>
```

```
$('#newAccessPoint').blur(function() {
    if($('#newAccessPoint').val().length > 0) {
            $('#selectAccessPoint').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4TRt/

Comment: Ahhh, very cool. Thank you.  But James' method has more functionality.